# data mining project Dilemma

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, prediction, logistic-regression

I research a set of data, consisting of two data files:
The first contains user id id artists and ranking of users for artists that want to rank.
The second data file contains id and name artists

I have chosen research question which is:
Is the artist is Popular or not?

In other words,by given the new singer, who will not found in the data file, using algorithms, we will classify it as an artist and to know if it is a popular or not.

For Prediction step I chose to use  logistic regression method
But my problem is earlier.
I do not know how, technically, to determine who from the existing data will be defined as successful as an artist who is unsuccessful.

I thought of some  methods, for example:k-means with k=2 (but in this method i have a problem with function disance),knn with k=2 etc.

I need guidance ,refers to how i will make to clustering to the Existing data
and general tips to the project.
thank you.

Comment: Don't expect clustering to do magic for you...

Comment: Please use semi supervised classification instead of clustering.

Comment: So you have a response variable "Ranking" and one (!) predictor "ArtistName". (1) This is not clustering, it is a classification problem. (2) What type of pattern do you hope to discover? Artists with short names are ranked higher? Artist Names with a lot of Consonants are ranked higher?